# How to correctly javascript these?

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

I have this .iim running with browser extension imacros for firefox:

```
SET rndSecWait EVAL("180 + Math.floor(Math.random()*11)")
WAIT SECONDS={{rndSecWait}}
```

How do i set the same code but for a .js file, i try with this code:

```
var macroStart; macroStart ="CODE:";
macroStart +="SET rndSecWait EVAL("180 + Math.floor(Math.random()*11)")" + "\n";
macroStart +="WAIT SECONDS={{rndSecWait}}" + "\n";
```

But i get this error when i try to run it:SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, line 2 (Error code: -991)

Silly question for this site maybe i don't know, but perhaps someone will help me, thanks in advance.

Greetings...

Comment: `But i get nothing when i try to run it.` - where are you trying to run it? you've set a var, macroStart, with some string data in it ... then do nothing with macroStart  (plus your code is actually invalid syntax so your browser console would be showing an error)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer coding Imacros scripts as .js scripts - that gives you much more power.
Copy this code below and save it e.g. as code.js and run from Imacros.
That's solution for your question, I coded:

```
    var wait_time = Math.floor(Math.random()*11) + 180;
    var url = "https://www.google.com";

    var visit_url = [
        'CODE:',
        'WAIT SECONDS=' + wait_time,
        'URL GOTO=' + url
    ].join('\n');

    iimPlay(visit_url);
```

Runs ok for me: Firefox 35.0.1, iMacros for Firefox 8.9.7, Windows 7.
If you have any questions - ask.